# Adding variably named fields to Python classes

Tags: python

I have a python class, and I need to add an arbitrary number of arbitrarily long lists to it. The names of the lists I need to add are also arbitrary. For example, in PHP, I would do this:

```
class MyClass {

}

$c = new MyClass();
$n = "hello"
$c.$n = array(1, 2, 3);
```

How do I do this in Python?

I'm also wondering if this is a reasonable thing to do. The alternative would be to create a dict of lists in the class, but since the number and size of the lists is arbitrary, I was worried there might be a performance hit from this.

If you are wondering what I'm trying to accomplish, I'm writing a super-lightweight script interpreter. The interpreter walks through a human-written list and creates some kind of byte-code. The byte-code of each function will be stored as a list named after the function in an "app" class. I'm curious to hear any other suggestions on how to do this as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `setattr`.

```
>>> class A(object):
...     pass
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> f = 'field'
>>> setattr(a, f, 42)
>>> a.field
42
```

Answer (score 1):

I would write it the simplest way for now, and profile next, and then look to optimize specific elements.

Let's remember the KISS principle.

Comment: lol, sure, but I just wanted to clarify, it sounds like you're still in the dreaming stage, so I would wait till you've got a working prototype because this sounds like a specific optimization. The dict list is fine.

Comment: I have some mock classes and I'm gradually filling them out. I was at the stage where I was figuring out how to hold the compiled data of a script. But really, so far I've done far more thinking and dreaming than code, because there's threads involved and I'm trying not to blow my foot off :)